# Upload Blob via Azure SDK using SAS Token and custom domain

Tags: azure-sdk-.net

We have created a CNAME record for our Azure Blob Storage account.

Before: `https://example.blob.core.windows.net/zips/example.zip`

After: `https://example.com/zips/example.zip`

This works fine for accessing blobs.

However we want to also upload blobs via the SDK

`

```
Uri uriToken = await getTokenAsync(...);
var blob = new CloudBlockBlob(uriToken);
blob.UploadFromStream(...)
```

`

Real token: `http://example.blob.core.windows.net/zips/example.zip?sv=2016-05-31&sr=b&sig=szA%2BtKRsDhHqgblkasdiBRM25gslerJ1rSKwM6UdrPg%3D&se=2019-05-21T09%3A43%3A34Z&sp=cw` works fine

Replace the host:
`https://example.com/zips/example.zip?sv=2016-05-31&sr=b&sig=szA%2BtKRsDhHqgblkasdiBRM25gslerJ1rSKwM6UdrPg%3D&se=2019-05-21T09%3A43%3A34Z&sp=cw`

Throws a very generic error:

```
An error occurred while sending the request.
   at Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.<ExecuteAsync>d__1`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlockBlob.<UploadFromStreamAsyncHelper>d__31.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
```

Comment: Azure storage does not yet natively support HTTPS with custom domains. You can currently use Azure CDN to access blobs by using custom domains over HTTPS. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-custom-domain-name . Are you currently using Azure CDN to access the blob and facing this error ?